# Droplet cannot connect to external MySQL, Connection refused in Digital Ocean

Tags: mysql, database, digital-ocean, droplet

I created a MySQL database and a Droplet on Digital Ocean, whenever I try to connect the Droplet to the DB using PHP or JS, I get the Connection refused error, but when accessing the DB on my localhost (using mysql workbench or php), I can normally.

What we know so far, apparently the Droplet does not have access to the external DB, since I can connect.

- My db credentials are correct.
- The droplet was added to the DB's list of trusted sources, allowing remote access, so much so that my IP was also placed, so I can access it through localhost.

Does anyone have any idea what this Connection refused error might be? I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days :(

Answer (score 1):

Guys I found out what it was, I installed a csf firewall and didn't add the database IP to the whitelist and solved the problem.